# How to get sum of all positive number from file?

Tags: python

I am solving this question but I don't know why it fails all my test cases.It always print EMPTY file in all my test cases. It has two parts first read file before -999 and sum all the positive number before -999 and if file is empty then return empty. The original problem is in the picture. Can someone please go through this code?  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWhWh.png

```
with open('/home/salman/Desktop/input.txt', 'r') as f:
first_line = f.readline()
#print(first_line)
for line in f :
    line = line.strip()
    mylist.append(line)
    mylist = list(map(int, mylist))

f.close()


def ifyes():
    if len(mylist) == 0:
        print("Empty")
    else:
        if -999 in mylist:
            print("yes -999 in list")
            print("Your numbers in file are :", mylist)
            index = mylist.index(-999)
            print("Index of -999 is :", index)
            print("Number before -999 in file are :", mylist[0:index])
            newlist = mylist[0:index]
            print("Numbers in new list:", newlist)
            theSum(newlist)
        else:
            theSum(mylist)
```

Comment: `mylist.append(line)
    mylist = list(map(int, mylist))` is bad. change it to `mylist.append(int(line))`

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in the question. It is not clear which lines belong to the `with` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you read your list is wrong. Can you try with:

```py
mylist = []
with open('/home/salman/Desktop/input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        mylist.append(int(line.strip()))
```

Comment: this wont work as expected because map returns a generator, so either use `int `directly or wrap the whole thing in a `next()`

Comment: yes i read like this but the point i have to skip the first number in my file for example 6,5,-4,6,7,-9999,-5,7 so i have to read from 5 and keep reading before -999 and then take the sum of positive number between 5 and -999